# Contact Form 7 validation trigger event

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

When user clicks on submit button for the contact form 7 form, I want the page to scroll to the validation message section.

**My approach:**

I am using jQuery `on click` event for the submit button and on click scrolling the page to validation message section.

I am sure that it is not correct. Because on click it scrolls to the section but the message has not yet come through ajax.

So, is there a way to create an event when validation is done in contact form 7 and use that to scroll down.

Comment: you can use setTimeout function of js @MarkWilson

Comment: that won't be correct. Time may vary to submit the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Contact Form 7 triggers `wpcf7:invalid` in this case.** You can use this trigger:

```
$(window).on('wpcf7:invalid', function() {
    // let's scroll
});
```

Source: https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/js/scripts.js (Line: 109)

Comment: Nope, not working here. None of these event triggers work, at all, and are completely undocumented.

Comment: As you can see in the source code (IMO the best documentation) linked above in line 109, the trigger is still there. It should still work.

Comment: weird - I couldn't get this format to work at all. I had to use the DOM events seen here: https://contactform7.com/dom-events/. Source code is documentation in the same way that looking at an open Ikea box is instructions ;)

Answer (score 5):

Given the variety of responses on this topic the plugin developer seems to change their mind about how this should work every 5 minutes. Currently (Q1 2017) this is the working method:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7invalid', function( event ) {
  alert( "Fire!" );
}, false );
```

And the valid events are:

- **wpcf7invalid** — Fires when an Ajax form submission has completed
  successfully, but mail hasn’t been sent because there are fields with
  invalid input.
- **wpcf7spam** — Fires when an Ajax form submission has
  completed successfully, but mail hasn’t been sent because a possible
  spam activity has been detected.
- **wpcf7mailsent** — Fires when an Ajax
  form submission has completed successfully, and mail has been sent.
- **wpcf7mailfailed** — Fires when an Ajax form submission has completed
  successfully, but it has failed in sending mail.
- **wpcf7submit** — Fires
  when an Ajax form submission has completed successfully, regardless
  of other incidents.

Sauce: https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Comment: works perfect, and control the listeners separately genius :D

Answer (score 0):

This does the job too. If anyone is interested.

```
$('.wpcf7-form').ajaxComplete( function(){    
      if($(this).hasClass('invalid') || $(this).hasClass('sent')){
            $('.forkit-curtain').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".wpcf7-response-output").first().offset().top + 100
            }, 2000);
      }
    });
```